# How to check if user has disable internet?

Tags: android, android-manifest, internet-connection

My app needs internet connection so it  check if user have connection or not. But it check that only when activity starts so how I can detect if user has no connection after activity is started?

HERE IS CODE WHAT I USE TO DETECT CONNECTION WHEN ACTIVITY STARTS:

```
@Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main );

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            if (!info.isConnected()) {
            }
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(hello.this, connectionerror.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            hello.this.finish();
        }
```

..... my apps other code continues here........

Comment: Have you tried placing the connectivity code inside a method? That way you can call it whenever you want without code reuse.

Answer (score 3):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`.  You can either look in the intent (for what network changed), or just re-check with the `ConnectivityManager`.

Comment: Not very good question, but nice answer. The CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcast sounds very useful. Thanks

Comment: @Erich Douglass How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe it is a very late answer, but if anyone wants to use a broadcast receiver for checking the connectivity, this might be a helpful link: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/monitor-wifi-status-and-information.html